# API-Gateway proxy service (Netflix Eureka Server) not showing running instances (Spring Boot Microservices)

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

Basically, I'm building microservice(s) architecture, where I want to implement an API gateway that acts as a proxy to route API requests to other spring boot applications from the api-gateway.
I created a new Spring Boot application called 'ct-api-gateway-proxy-service' to be the API gateway and added the @EnableEurekaServer annotation to the running file. It is running on port 8888. However, when I run the localhost:8888, the server is up but I don't see the connected microservice as a running instance. I also added localhost:8888/eureka but I get a whitepage label error.

The connecting microservice client is called 'CT-cryptography-core-lib'. This is an existing spring boot application that I'm trying to connect to the API gateway. This application is annotated with '@EnableEurekaClient'. However, when I run this application, it runs successfully but I don't actually see it running on the Eureka server UI (localhost:8888) as an instance on the gateway server. I also don't see any Eureka information on the stack trace of this application.
My end goal is to link all microservices, including this one and route API calls to them.

This is my application.properties for 'ct-api-gateway-proxy-service':

```
server.port=8888
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8888/eureka
spring.application.name=ct-api-gateway-proxy-service

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=CT-cryptography-core-lib
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://CT-cryptography-core-lib
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/encryption/
```

This is my application file for 'ct-api-gateway-proxy-service' code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class CtApiGatewayProxyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CtApiGatewayProxyServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties file for the 'CT-cryptography-core-lib' microservice:

```
server.port= 4000
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8888/eureka
spring.application.name=CT-cryptography-core-lib

#---LOGGING---
#FLAG FOR OUTPUTTING THE LOGS TO EXTERNAL SERVICE (S3) OR TO LOCAL FILE
log.output:local
```

My main Application for 'CT-cryptography-core-lib':

```
package com.ct.cryptography.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: UDPATE - I'm able to now see the API-gateway as a running instance after I changed the eureka.client.register-with-eureka to be 'true'. However, I still don't see the CT-cryptography-core-lib service running in the instances of the server